# HoW to open url in anotherview when user click on row of UITableview?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5

I want to open url  in another view when user select row.

Comment: 1 Question asked in 3 different ways.... Edit your question so that you are clear and we understand it clearly

Comment: Did you tried anything ?

Comment: i have confusion in how can i load url in another view.

Comment: I don't know why this question has been down voted and closed. Couldn't find any solution and its needed to me (Swift 3.0). This is a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just property synthesize that url in your another view and just set the value with selected item .. just see example bellow...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
yourNextViewController *objNextView = [[yourNextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourNextViewController" bundle:nil];

    objNextView.strURL = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];;
    [objNextView.strURL retain];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objNextView animated:YES];
    [objNextView release];
}
```

and property, synthesize like bellow..

```
@interface yourNextViewController : UIViewController{
       NSString *strURL;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain)    NSString *strURL;
@end

@implementation yourNextViewController
@synthesize strURL;
```

after use this `strURL`

Comment: Okey this work, but i have a multiple link in tableview, i want to open all this link in another view when i select any particular row,if i select any row than it has to open link which is selected in another view..

Comment: not understand .. just tell me in detail.. :(

Comment: ok..i display 8 records in Tableview.and each record have own url.and i want to open this url in another view,if i select first row than open url according to row in another view,same as if i select second row than it has to open url according to row in another view.i don't want to create different nib for open every url ,i want to open every url in same nib file,if user select 1st row than open url in nib,and if select 2nd row than open url in same nib.so this type i want to do..and sorry for this long description bcuz my english is little bit poor..

Comment: its ok dude.. :) and for that just pass that url in your next class and just reload webview with your this new one url...

Comment: thanks paras..but can u explain with some code..

Comment: hi paras..can u tell me that how to stream data over bluetooth between iOS devices..tell me What i have to need.Which frame work will use.?

Comment: now not idea about it dude, but i will post comment when i will free :)

Comment: i'm stuck at this point.is there any tutorial for that.

Comment: sure , now i have work and so sorry for not helpful to you.. but i will post atlist link if get some tutorial about it..

Comment: nik6015d2d@gmail.com..this is my mail id,if u will get answer than tell me ..

Answer (score 1):

Use UIWebVIew for opening a link in another view.

Use tableView's didSelectRowAtIndexPath - to get the selected row of tableview.

On didSelect table view delegate - Navigate to required View - load URL using UIWebView

Comment: can u explain with some code???

Comment: check this link : http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/08/uiwebview-tutorial.html

Comment: @arun.s link is not working. any other link please?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tbView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath %d",indexPath.row);
    // Either load your url here using the UIWebView or use the below code to open URL in safari.
    // [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hereURLYouWantToOpen]];
}
```

To load the URL in UIWebView you can use the below code :

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initwithFrame:CGRectMake(your co-ordinate)];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your URL"]]];
```